# Is it possible to disable admin rights of a malware?

Tags: malware, uninstallation, device-administrator

There is a smartphone with anroid 5.1. Another user installed an app from a non-verified source (some hacks for Clash of Clans afaik). To uninstall it I have to drop its administrator rights in `Settings -> Security -> Device administrators`. The problem is that when I click to uncheck it, device locks and I hear two check sounds (check and uncheck, I suppose).

When I go to settings again the checkbox is still checked. The same behaviour when using safe mode.

How to remove malware-originated administrators?

Comment: Is  the device rooted?

Comment: I don't even know what does it mean. Just a recently bought one.

Comment: Okay I presume it is not. But did you first try to force-close the app then disable the admin rights?

Comment: What is a force-close? It is not presented in a list of launched apps, but it generates fullscreen ad popups.

Comment: The adware might be present in the app list. Look for an unusual app name

Comment: Just SmartcardService `org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service:remote` looks unusual. I can't see both apps that are fake administratos in the list.

Comment: But com.simaliance.openmobileapi.service is a valid package name for STK services or SmartCardService

Comment: Download Uninstall from the Play Store, it will list all apps and their package name pretty better. Look for weird app name or package name.

Comment: But what does prevent from changing admin rights to `Clash of Clans`? Another application, not itself?

Comment: Clash of Clans don't have such rights. I think there is another app, an adware, that was installed when the user installed the hack. Or the full screen ads are generated by the modded Clash of Clans

Comment: Could you please create a full answer how to remove undesirable adm rights?

Comment: I would suggest installing security 360 from Google Play and see if that removes the ad ware.